# setPageSize correct use in Qt5.14

Tags: c++, qt5

I'm using Qt5.14.0 and re-building a program compiled using a previous Qt version, according to the use of QPdfWriter, This warning appears:
'virtual void QPdfWriter::setPageSize(QPagedPaintDevice::PageSize)' is deprecated: Use setPageSize(QPageSize(id)) instead [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
My instructions are the following:

```
QPdfWriter writer(ReportToBePrinted);
QPainter painter(&writer);
QFont TitleFont("Arial", 20, QFont::Bold);
QFont SubTitleFont("Arial", 16, QFont::Bold);
QFont TextFont("Arial",8,QFont::Normal);
writer.setPageSize(QPagedPaintDevice::A4);
```

What's the correct way to use "SetPageSize" in my program, to avoid the warning?

Comment: Looks like just including QPrinter header instantly generates this warning.